# stack data and restructure without using var to cases or casestovar in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have the following situation: a loop (stack data) with only 1 index variable and with multiple items corresponding to the statements, as in the picture below (sorry it is Excel, but is the same as in SPSS): 
[stack data - cases on multiple lines, but never filling for 1 respondent all the columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXbco.png)

I want to reach to the following situation but without using `casestovars` to restructure, because that creates a lot of empty variables. I remember for older versions it was a command like Update, which was moving up the cases, to reach the following result: 
[reducing the cases per respondent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8oZJ.png)

Like starting from this:

```
ID Index Q1_1 Q1_2 Q1_3 Q1_4 Q1_5 Q1_6 
1   1     1    1    
1   2                1    1
1   3                         1     1
```

To reach to this:

```
ID Q1_1 Q1_2 Q1_3 Q1_4 Q1_5 Q1_6 
1    1    1    1   1     1   1
```

But without using `casestovars`. Is there any command in SPSS syntax for this?

Thank you very much, have a nice day!

Comment: Hello Ania, welcome to stackoverflow :) The first thing which comes to mind is to use a dynamic `lag`, where the function's parameter would be the value of the index. Did not test this, though, and I am not sure how to do this for each ID separately

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure how variable your data structure is likely to be in reality but if as demo'ed where you have only a single response for each `q1_1 to q1_6` per respondent ID, then the below would be sufficient:

```
dataset declare dsAgg.
aggregate outfile="dsAgg" /break=respid /q1_1 to q1_6=max(q1_1 to q1_6).
```

Also not sure of the significance of duplicate index values within the same respondent IDs, if this was intended or not.

Answer (score 1):

The following syntax could do the job -

```
* first we'll recreate your example data.
data list list/respid index q1_1 to q1_6.
begin data
1,1,1,,,,,
1,2,,2,,,,
1,3,,,1,,,
1,4,,,,2,,
1,5,,,,,1,
1,6,,,,,,2
2,1,3,,,,,
2,1,,4,,,,
2,2,,,5,,,
2,2,,,,4,,
2,3,,,,,3,
2,3,,,,,,2
end data.

* now to work: first thing is to make sure the data from each ID are together.
sort cases by respid index.

* the loop will fill down the data to the last line of each ID.
do repeat qq=q1_1 to q1_6.
if respid=lag(respid) and missing(qq) qq=lag(qq).
end repeat.

* the following lines will help recognize the last line for each ID and select it.
compute lineNR=$casenum.
aggregate /outfile=* mode=ADDVARIABLES/break=respid/MXlineNR=max(lineNR).
select if lineNR=MXlineNR.
exe.
```